# Factorize javascript/jquery code for hiding modal when click outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that work but I don't know how to factorize it. It seems I could be able to do it as they're basically the same code  first for desktyop then for touch devices:

```
//desktop

  $(document).mouseup(function (e)
  {
      var container = $(".messenger");
      if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
          && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
      {
          container.empty();
          container.off( 'click', clickDocument );
      }
  });



// Touch devices like IPAD and IPHONE we can use following code

$(document).on('touchstart', function (e) {
    var container = $(".messenger");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.empty();
        container.off( 'click', clickDocument );
    }
});
```

Comment: you just need a stand alone function and when the event is triggered, call it

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "factorize", and I couldn't find an applicable definition on google. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite easy:

```
// desktop (mouseup)
// or Touch devices like IPAD and IPHONE we can use following code

  $(document).on('mouseup touchstart', function (e)
  {
      var container = $(".messenger");
      if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
          && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
      {
          container.empty();
          container.off( 'click', clickDocument );
      }
  });
```

Comment: Why switch from `on` to `bind`?

Comment: @Mathletics Didn't really "switched", since the OP's version didn't use `on()`, but dedicated `mouseup()` and `touchstart()` methods. So I somewhat automtically used `bind()` but sure it could be `on()` too.

Comment: The reason I ask is because [in the docs for `bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) they state: _As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document._

Comment: @Mathletics Again, you're right: it's better to follow the recommended methods. I intially reacted by habit.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
var onMouseUp = function (e) {
    var container = $(".messenger");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.empty();
        container.off( 'click', clickDocument );
    }
};

// For Desktop
$(document).mouseup(onMouseUp);

// For devices
$(document).on('touchstart', onMouseUp);
```

Comment: What's the value of using a function expression in this case?

Comment: Avoid defining it twice and re-using it instead.

Comment: I mean, as opposed to writing it like this: `function onMouseUp () { /**/ }` By convention I guess, the function expression form usually returns a value, right?

Comment: Just order (personal opinion). Check this for info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 1):

may you can try this:

```
var eventTouch = function(e){    
    var container = $(".messenger");
        if (!container.is(e.target) 
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
           {
            container.empty();
            container.off( 'click', clickDocument );
           }
    }

$(document).mouseup(eventTouch);
$(document).on('touchstart', eventTouch);
```

Comment: What's the value of using a function expression in this case?

Comment: only create one function for a twice events, and it's more clean, you can order your code on sections, one for definition methods and one to implementation